# Database connection, checking database path

Tags: iphone

i have created database in sqlite manager. my project get terminated due to exception. when i took the help of break point then i get the "bad access" at line 3rd. 
I am unable to get the solution for the problem at 3rd line.

```
-(void)checkAndCreateDB
{
    BOOL Success;
    //NSFileManager maintains file
    NSFileManager *FileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    //Checks Database Path
    Success = [FileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbpath];
    //If file exists it return true
    if(Success)return;
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbname];
[FileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:dbpath error:nil];
    [FileManager release];
}
```

Here dbpath=

```
/Users/gauravmurghai/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/E48F72FD-5CC9-438C-B412-7D16FEF8DD8C/Documents/dbnitu.sqlite
```

Error is displayed at line 3:“EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

line 3 is:  Success = [FileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbpath];
I cannot understand where the problem is?Unable to overcome this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)checkAndCreateDB
{

    //NSFileManager maintains file
    NSFileManager *FileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    //Checks Database Path
    if([FileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbpath]);
    //If file exists it return true
    return;
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbname];
[FileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:dbpath error:nil];
    [FileManager release];
}
```